# Get level of link within nested list?

Tags: jquery, nested

```
<ul>
    <li class="solution device">
    <a href="#">Device</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Apple</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">iPad Air</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPad Mini</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
            </ul><!-- // end 3rd level -->
            </li>           
        </ul><!-- // end 2nd level -->
    </li><!-- // end 1st level -->
</ul>
```

If a user clicks on any of the links I want to know what level it's in. So if you clicked iPhone it would be level = 3 (or 2 if it's indexed from of 0). I can hard code something but am looking for a dynamic solution that can work with any # of levels and no classes on the li or href. Any smart ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question by the way +1 for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (Added an id `top`) to the top `ul` element

```
$('#top a').click(function(){
    var $lis = $(this).parentsUntil('#top', 'li');
    console.log($lis.length)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mmp6S/)

Comment: @wutang I think you can accept ArunPJohny answer because in my answer I did not consider that you have link elements. So, as usual ArunPJohny beat me :(. He is very helpful person anyway :)

Comment: @Phoenix the problem is there are other `ul` elements in the sub menus so just finding the parents count will not work... we need to find the `li` parents between the clicked element and the top ul

Comment: Right i understand after i saw document. We should specify filter for that

Answer (score 1):

You  can do following:

```
$('ul#root_id').on('click', 'li', function(){
   console.log($(this).parentsUntil('ul#root_id', 'li').length);
});
```

Here `'ul#root_id'` is your root ul element. And read about [parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/).